# Neo4j/GraphQL - get the last node in a linked list in order to continue the linked list with newly created nodes

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-graphql-js

I have a linked list of Posts in a Group. A Group has a FIRST_POST and then subsequent NEXT_POST relationships. The GraphQL typedef looks like this:

```
type Group {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    membersList: [User] @relation(direction: IN, name: "MEMBER_OF")
    engagesIn: Conversation @relation(direction: OUT, name: "ENGAGES_IN")
    posts: [Post] @cypher(statement: """
        MATCH (g:Group {id: this.id})-[:FIRST_POST|NEXT_POST*]->(post:Post) 
        RETURN post
    """)
    createdAt: DateTime
    updatedAt: DateTime
}
```

The cypher query `MATCH (g:Group {id: this.id})-[:FIRST_POST|NEXT_POST*]->(post:Post) RETURN post` returns all of a specific Group's posts. I want to create a new Post and add it to the Group in my schema's typedef. Here's one stab at it that I know is not correct, but is where my current efforts are:

```
CreatePost(body: String!, userId: ID!): Post
    @cypher(
      statement: """
        MATCH (u:User {id: $userId})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)-[:FIRST_POST|NEXT_POST*]->(lp:Post) return Last(collect(p))
        CREATE (p:Post { id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: $body, createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime() }) 
        WITH p, lp
        MATCH (u:User)
        WHERE u.id = $userId 
        CREATE (p)<-[:WROTE]-(u)
        CREATE (p)-[:NEXT_POST]->(lp)
        RETURN u, p
    """)
```

This is a custom mutation that accept post body and userId arguments. This line `MATCH (u:User {id: $userId})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)-[:FIRST_POST|NEXT_POST*]->(lp:Post) return Last(collect(p))` would return the last post, though I know I cannot return here and haven't successfully found a way to alias that MATCH. Ultimately I need to CREATE the NEXT_POST relationship off of the last NEXT_POST in that group with `CREATE (p)-[:NEXT_POST]->(<LAST POST IN GROUP>)`. The first line also uses the userId to find the group as Users are MEMBER_OF only one Group and Posts belong to only one Group.

Comment: Try introducing a pointer relationship that points to the latest post -> https://neo4j.com/blog/moving-relationships-neo4j/

Comment: Thanks! Looking into that now. Yeah, we may have set up strangely where the Group to Post relationship is only linear aka Group->FIRST_POST->NEXT_POST->NEXT_POST etc. The Post nodes do not have any other relationship to Group.

Answer (score 0):

So, some confusion on my part. Someone else created the schema with FIRST_POST being the most recently created post rather than the first post created. Renaming it to NEWEST_POST, I can no do this:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: $userId})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)-[rel:NEWEST_POST]->(previousNewestPost:Post)
DELETE rel
CREATE (p:Post { id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: 'test new post', createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime() }) 
WITH p, g, previousNewestPost
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = $userId 
CREATE (p)<-[:WROTE]-(u)
CREATE (p)<-[:NEWEST_POST]-(g)
CREATE (p)-[:NEXT_POST]->(previousNewestPost)
RETURN u, p
```

to create a new post and update the relationships accordingly.